# Connecting users to existing records with emails AFTER account activation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

**My issue**: Once a user has an account but creates a new Order while not signed in, the order will not connect to the account through the email used.

But when a user  doesn't have an account, they create an order with example@example.com --- and then sign up with example@example.com, the orders will connect and appear.

I want it so when a user has an account already, but then creates an Order with the accounts same email while not signed in, the Order connects.

**My user.rb model** that makes connection possible:

```
    after_create :connect_orders

  def connect_orders
    Order.where(email: self.email).update_all(buyer_id: self.id)
  end
```

So when the emails are the same, it will connect.

I tested this for already approved devise User accounts , create an order with the same email, then the order won't show up.  It's like once there is already an account, the code doesn't work.  Unless, is the code not set up to work like that and where have i gone wrong?

Comment: Because when i sign back into the account the order(s) don't appear.  Shouldn't the after_create work regardless?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created an `after_create` callback in your `User` model. That means the code to connect orders in only ran after the creation of a user. It will not run if you create an order and a matching user already exists.

If you want to connect new orders to existing users automatically when you create the order then you will need to add a callback to your `Order` model. Something like the following might work:

```
# in app/model/order.rb
before_validation :connect_user

private
def connect_user
  self.buyer ||= User.find_by(email: self.email)
end
```

Comment: omg lmao.  thanks looks good to me.  ill test this out and should work.

Comment: I get a: `NoMethodError (undefined method `user' for #<Order:0x00007f6f781c0018>):` with this.

Comment: I've tried a dozen more variants but can't seem to get it to work!

Comment: I updated my answer. I overreacted that your association is named buyer instead of user.

Comment: See now you smart.  Didn't even need to show you the user model had a buyer and seller as my user

Comment: Would there be a benefit to using "`after_create`" insted of `before_validation` ?

Comment: After create would send two queries to the database, therefore before validation will be slightly faster in this case.